# Should the WWW-Authenticate realm parameter be encoded?

Tags: oauth, oauth-1.0a, www-authenticate

When building the WWW-Authenticate header value for OAuth/[OAuth1a](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a) it calls for percent-encoding the parameters. The spec and implementations are ambiguous on whether the `realm` parameter should be percent-encoded or not.

Section [5.4.1.  Authorization Header](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_header) of the spec reads:

> The OAuth Protocol Parameters are sent in the Authorization header the
>   following way:
>
> 1. Parameter names and values are encoded per Parameter Encoding.
> 2. For each parameter, the name is immediately followed by an '=' character (ASCII code 61), a '"' character (ASCII code 34), the parameter value (MAY be empty), and another '"' character (ASCII code 34).
> 3. Parameters are separated by a comma character (ASCII code 44) and OPTIONAL linear whitespace per [RFC2617].
> 4. The OPTIONAL realm parameter is added and interpreted per [RFC2617], section 1.2.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>             Authorization: OAuth realm="http://sp.example.com/",
>             oauth_consumer_key="0685bd9184jfhq22",
>             oauth_token="ad180jjd733klru7",
>             oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>             oauth_signature="wOJIO9A2W5mFwDgiDvZbTSMK%2FPY%3D",
>             oauth_timestamp="137131200",
>             oauth_nonce="4572616e48616d6d65724c61686176",
>             oauth_version="1.0"
> ```

If these steps are meant to be taken in order, then it seems like only the OAuth specific parameters are meant to be url encoded.

If these steps are not meant to be taken in order, then maybe the `realm` parameter is included in step 1. However, the WWW-Authenticate header example in the [OAuth1a](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a) spec shows the realm as `realm="http://sp.example.com/"` which is not percent-encoding the colon or the slashes.

To make matters more confusing, it seems this varies from implementation to implementation. Many OAuth implementations give no special treatment to the parameters and simply percent-encode all of them, but other OAuth implementations give special treatment to the `realm` parameter and exclude it from percent-encoding.

What is the correct behavior for adding the `realm` parameter to the WWW-Authenticate header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WWW-Authenticate header and the `realm` parameter, in particular, are defined by [rfc2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) and [rfc7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235), which do not say anything about encoding. [rfc7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) shows an example where the spaces in `"Login to \"apps\""` are not percent-encoded.

[rfc2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) and [rfc7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) are the authority on the WWW-Authenticate header and `realm` parameter while the [OAuth1a](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a) spec is only the authority on the additional OAuth specific parameters. Therefore the `realm` parameter should **not** be percent-encoded and section [5.4.1](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_header) of the OAuth1a spec should be interpreted to only be talking about **OAuth Protocol Parameters** with regards to percent-encoding.